Map from product spaces is open
Let $X,Y$ be topological spaces and let $f:X\times Y\to X\times Y$ be a map such that $\pi_1\circ f=\pi_1$, where $\pi_1(x,y)=x$ is the projection on the first topological space. Suppose that, for any fixed $x\in X$ and any open set $V\subset Y$, the set $\{\pi_2(f(x,y)):y\in V\}\subset Y$ is open. Does it mean that the map $f$ is an open map?
Namely, can I deduce that for any open set $U\subset X$, the set
$$
f(U\times V)=\bigcup_{x\in U}\{f(x,y):y\in V\}
$$
is an "open union" of "open sets" and so it is open in the product topology? 
Maybe this reminds me something about Baire spaces.

$\mbox{Id}_X$ has domain and codomain $X$, how is it equal to $\pi_1\circ f$?

Sorry, I have fixed it now.

Notice that $f=\pi_1\times g$ for some $g: X\times Y \rightarrow Y$

Are you assuming $f$ is continuous? You say “map” which sometimes means continuous functions (eg in Munkres) and sometimes just means function.

@Malady No, $f$ is not continuous, it is just a map.

As Malady suggested in the comments, since $\pi_1\circ f=\pi_1$, then $f(x,y)=(\pi_1(x,y),g(x,y))$, where $g:X\times Y\to Y$. Since $\pi_1$ is an open map, it suffices to show that $g$ is open.
Now to prove that $g$ is open, by the product topology, it is enough to prove that for every $A_1\in\mathcal{T}_X$ and $A_2\in\mathcal{T}_Y$, we get that $g(A_1\times A_2)\in\mathcal{T}_Y$. Also, notice that the second condition of your statement is equivalent to say that $g(x,V)\in\mathcal{T}_Y$ for all $x\in X$ and $V\in\mathcal{T}_Y$. Hence,
$$g(A_1\times A_2)=g\left(\bigcup_{x\in A_1}x\times A_2\right)=\bigcup_{x\in A_1}g(x,A_2)\in\mathcal{T}_Y,$$
since it is expressed as a union of open sets. Thus, $g$ is an open map.
